# Ruby on rails - basic forms - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

I've problem with my "subscriber". It should just add an email to db with symptom active/inactive. It gaves me this error - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

```
    Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <div id="subscriber">
**2:    <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>**
3:      <%= f.label :email %>
4:      <%= f.text_field :email %>
5:      <%= f.hidden_field :active, :value => true %>
```

Here is model:

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base 

  attr_accessor :email, :active

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<div id="subscriber">
    <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :active, :value => true %>
        <%= f.submit t('.submit') %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is controller:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])

    if @subscriber.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Thx for subscription"
      @subscriber.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

Here are routes:
    resources :subscribers

I'm new with RoR, so if you need some more logs or info let me know. Thx alot.

Comment: try removing that initialize method

Comment: Than it works, but I need somehow pass the :email and :active to the model. I've also tried to give a default value for :active because I thought it might want to have some value not only nil so I've set active = true but same result. Some other idea? Thx for comment/answer jvnill.

Comment: sorry i don't get your issue. with your current code, i don't see any issues with saving the records to the db.

Comment: Just curious, if you are sending the values of email and active already by form and then saving them to database via controller then why you need to pass them to model. What purpose do they solve?

Comment: You are right guys, my fault. First I've started it as ActiveModel so that's the reason why the method is there. Now I know that it inherits it from ActiveRecord. So the final code of model is this. ` class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base 

  attr_accessible :email, :active
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i

end`